# Спиннер загрузки, если несколько запросов одновременно Vue js

Tags: http, vue.js, vuex

На проекте я использую вариант с перехватом запросов для отображения спиннера загрузки

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
  store.dispatch('loadingToggle', true);
  next((response) => {
    store.dispatch('loadingToggle', false);
  })
})
```

Но если будет два или более запроса одновременно, то ведь спиннер скроется как только первый успешный запрос отработает. А как быть с остальными? Ведь данные еще могут быть не получены, а спиннера уже нет.

Comment: Я предполагаю, что одним из способов решения может быть обертка всех запросов в этот перехватчик.

Answer (score 0):

Я для себя решил по другому, на каждой странице пишу так:

```
  async created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('loaderOn')
    await this.$store.dispatch('первый вызов')
    await this.$store.dispatch('второй вызов')
    .....
    await this.$store.dispatch('последний')
    this.$store.dispatch('loaderOff')
  }
```

А от данных loadera на странице крутится спинер или показывается вся страница

Comment: А как быть, если запросы идут уже после хука created? Действия пользователя по добавлению комментария, отправлению письма, получения ответов.

Comment: Ну точно также, вешаем событие и к примеру async update () { ... }

Comment: Не лучший вариант

Comment: Не настаиваю, но для меня рабочий, т.к. при переходе по прямой ссылке только так смог перехватить, чтобы исключить все ошибки отсутствия данных. У меня сами данные на странице `v-if="loader"`

Answer (score 0):

Я немного подумал и пришел к выводу, что следующий вариант будет одним из наиболее подходящих вариантов.
Во `vuex` добавляем какой-нибудь `counter = 0` запросов. И при входящем запросе инкрементируем его на один. При получении ответа (либо после обработки ошибки, что тоже ответ) уменьшаем его на один. При равенстве нулю мы скрываем лоадер.

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
  store.dispatch('loadingToggle', true);
  store.dispatch('incrementCounter');
  next((response) => {
    store.dispatch('decrementCounter');
    if(store.state.сounter === 0); {
      store.dispatch('loadingToggle', false);
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Если речь о глобальном индикаторе загрузке, то можно посмотреть как сделано в фреймворке nuxt, там это через плагин `this.$nuxt.$loading`

Стартовать:

```
this.$nuxt.$loading.start()
```

Финишировать:

```
this.$nuxt.$loading.finish()
```

Можете по такому же принципу сделать себе плагин.

Для локальных индикаторов загрузки, которых на странице может быть несколько я себе написал такой плагин:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

// It makes it easy to launch an action in a component that is bound to the loading
Vue.prototype.$actionWithLoading = async function (action, loadingVariable = 'loading', ...arg) {
  this[loadingVariable] = true
  try {
    await action(...arg)
  } catch (e) {
    throw e // so that the error can be caught above
  } finally {
    this[loadingVariable] = false
  }
}
```

Самый просто вариант использования, где getData это асинхронный запрос:

```
this.$actionWithLoading(this.getData)
```

По умолчанию плагин запишет true в свойство loading когда начнется загрузка и false когда закончится.

Вариант использования когда несколько индикаторов:

```
this.$actionWithLoading(this.getNews, 'loadingNews')
this.$actionWithLoading(this.getUsers, 'loadingUsers')
```

Если надо передать аргументы:

```
this.$actionWithLoading(this.getNews, 'loadingNews', arg1)
this.$actionWithLoading(this.getUsers, 'loadingUsers', arg1, arg2, arg3...)
```